# Update the data into the database that insert into the correct rows

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have got a problem with update the data into the database. When I ran the code, it will input the data that start with `3061` to `3070` which it should have start with `3001` to `3010`.

When I try this:

```
for next_day, program_id in zip(nextday_list, program_id_list):
    value = program_id

    for i in range(0,10):
        if value == program_id:
           cur.execute("UPDATE programs SET program_id=? WHERE start_date=?",(value, next_day))
```

It will make the database table to show like this:

```
channel             |   start_date     |  program_id
101 BBC One South E |  20171111230000  |  3061
101 BBC One South E |  20171111233000  |  3062
101 BBC One South E |  20171112000000  |  3063
101 BBC One South E |  20171112013500  |  3064
101 BBC One South E |  20171112014000  |  3065
101 BBC One South E |  20171112060000  |  3066
101 BBC One South E |  20171112090000  |  3067
101 BBC One South E |  20171112102000  |  3068
101 BBC One South E |  20171112123000  |  3069
101 BBC One South E |  20171112133000  |  3070
102 BBC Two | 20171111232500  |  3061
102 BBC Two | 20171112010000  |  
102 BBC Two | 20171112023500  |  
102 BBC Two | 20171112060500  |  
102 BBC Two | 20171112065000  |  
102 BBC Two | 20171112073500  |  
102 BBC Two | 20171112083500  |  
102 BBC Two | 20171112093000  |  
102 BBC Two | 20171112130000  |  
102 BBC Two | 20171112140000  |
```

It should be:

```
channel             |   start_date     |  program_id
101 BBC One South E |  20171111230000  |  3001
101 BBC One South E |  20171111233000  |  3002
101 BBC One South E |  20171112000000  |  3003
101 BBC One South E |  20171112013500  |  3004
101 BBC One South E |  20171112014000  |  3005
101 BBC One South E |  20171112060000  |  3006
101 BBC One South E |  20171112090000  |  3007
101 BBC One South E |  20171112102000  |  3008
101 BBC One South E |  20171112123000  |  3009
101 BBC One South E |  20171112133000  |  3010
102 BBC Two | 20171111232500  |  3011
102 BBC Two | 20171112010000  |  3012
102 BBC Two | 20171112023500  |  3013
102 BBC Two | 20171112060500  |  3014
102 BBC Two | 20171112065000  |  3015
102 BBC Two | 20171112073500  |  3016
102 BBC Two | 20171112083500  |  3017
102 BBC Two | 20171112093000  |  3018
102 BBC Two | 20171112130000  |  3019
102 BBC Two | 20171112140000  |  3020
```

Here is the `program_id` data:

```
3001
3002
3003
3004
3005
3006
3007
3008
3009
3010
3011
3012
3013
3014
3015
3016
3017
3018
3019
3020
3021
3022
3023
3024
3025
3026
3027
3028
3029
3030
3031
3032
3033
3034
3035
3036
3037
3038
3039
3040
3041
3042
3043
3044
3045
3046
3047
3048
3049
3050
3051
3052
3053
3054
3055
3056
3057
3058
3059
3060
3061
3062
3063
3064
3065
3066
3067
3068
3069
3070
```

Here is the `program_id_list` list:

```
['3001', '3002', '3003', '3004', '3005', '3006', '3007', '3008', '3009', 
'3010', '3011', '3012', '3013', '3014', '3015', '3016', '3017', '3018', 
'3019', '3020', '3021', '3022', '3023', '3024', '3025', '3026', '3027', 
'3028', '3029', '3030', '3031', '3032', '3033', '3034', '3035', '3036', 
'3037', '3038', '3039', '3040', '3041', '3042', '3043', '3044', '3045', 
'3046', '3047', '3048', '3049', '3050', '3051', '3052', '3053', '3054', 
'3055', '3056', '3057', '3058', '3059', '3060', '3061', '3062', '3063', 
'3064', '3065', '3066', '3067', '3068', '3069', '3070']
```

Here is the `nextday_list` list:

```
['20171111224000', '20171111230000', '20171111233000', '20171112000000', 
'20171112013500', '20171112014000', '20171112060000', '20171112090000', 
'20171112102000', '20171112123000', '20171111224000', '20171111230000', 
'20171111233000', '20171112000000', '20171112013500', '20171112014000', 
'20171112060000', '20171112090000', '20171112102000', '20171112123000', 
'20171111224000', '20171111230000', '20171111233000', '20171112000000',         
'20171112013500', '20171112014000', '20171112060000', '20171112090000', 
'20171112102000', '20171112123000', '20171111224000', '20171111230000', 
'20171111233000', '20171112000000', '20171112013500', '20171112014000', 
'20171112060000', '20171112090000', '20171112102000', '20171112123000', 
'20171111224000', '20171111230000', '20171111233000', '20171112000000', 
'20171112013500', '20171112014000', '20171112060000', '20171112090000', 
'20171112102000', '20171112123000', '20171111224000', '20171111230000', 
'20171111233000', '20171112000000', '20171112013500', '20171112014000', 
'20171112060000', '20171112090000', '20171112102000', '20171112123000', 
'20171111224000', '20171111230000', '20171111233000', '20171112000000', 
'20171112013500', '20171112014000', '20171112060000', '20171112090000', 
'20171112102000', '20171112123000']
```

What I'm expecting to do is I want to input the 10 program ids for each channel in the same row as the `next_day` data which 10 program ids goes for bbc one, the other 10 goes for bbc two and so on.

Here is for example: Find the `next_day` data `20171111224000`, then find them in the database to match it then in the same row I want to input `3001`, then in the next row the `next_day` data show `20171111230000` I want to put `3002`, then `3003`, `3004`, `3005`...etc until to `3010` for each row. The same thing for the other channels.

Can you please show me an example how I could input the program id `3001` to `3010` to input them in the same row as the `next_day` data for bbc one, `3011` to `3020` for bbc two...etc??

Comment: any idea?????????????

Comment: SQL tables are unordered. Define "next row".

Comment: what you mean by define "next row"?

Comment: Put the rows in a random order. How would you find the one that you call "next"?

Comment: i dont know but i think i would have to use `next_day` so i can use to call "next". can you please post the code that would help to solve my problem?

Comment: I still do not understand what you are trying to do. (The values in `nextday_list` do not occur in the database, so whatis their purpose?)